# How can I implement a Javascript color picker

Tags: javascript, html, color-picker

I'm contemplating the development of a component for picking color off of a web page.
This is NOT a color selection component which allows you to choose a specific color off of a color wheel or pallete.
I'm referring to a component which will provide me with a crosshair to click o nthe specific spot on the page and "pick" the color under it.
I know, on the web, this is very complex.
I couldn't find a n existing component nor think of a good way to implement this other than complex markup inspection and image inspection.

Any pointers?

Comment: Sorry?
I didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: OK, found a few... but most really never supplied me with a relevant answer...

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has an add-on called "ColorZilla", check that out.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it, though its not exactly what I'm looking for. I need to embed this inside my own component.